# WSO2 Identity Server "Illegal Access attempt" (but only from different hosts)

Tags: wso2

I have two instances of WSO2 on two different machines, with the same policy published to both instances.  Both WSO2 instances have admin/admin.

I use SOAPUI (running on 192.168.0.9) to try to test against the EntitlementService webservice and:

- If I use SOAPUI to test against the EntitlementService webservice on the same machine that SOAPUI is running on (192.168.0.9), using either localhost or IP address, I get a XACML response with a Permit.  However,
- If I used SOAPUI to test against the EntitlementService webservice on the other machine (192.168.0.210), I get a XACML response with a Deny, and an "Illegal access attempt" error in the 192.168.0.210 WSO2 log:

> Illegal access attempt at [2014-05-12 15:26:47,0563] from IP address
>   192.168.0.9 while trying to authenticate access to service EntitlementService

In both cases above, I have BASIC authentication and the 'admin' username and password setup in SOAPUI.

If I run Tryit on the 192.168.0.210 WSO2 admin to test against the 192.168.0.210 WSO2, I get a Permit, i.e., this shows that the policy on the 192.168.0.210 should return a Permit.

Finally, I'm pretty sure that this is something with WSO2, and not with SOAPUI, as I also tested from the 192.168.0.9 machine using Firefox and a plugin called RESTclient, to test doing the POST of the XACML request in the content body.

Is there something in WSO2 Identity Server that would cause it to return a Deny if the requests are coming from a different machine?

Thanks,
Jim

P.S.  I'm seeing the following in the WSO2 wso2carbon.log file:

> TID: [0] [IS] [2014-05-12 15:59:40,798] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.authentication.AbstractAuthenticator} -  Invalid remote address detected. {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.authentication.AbstractAuthenticator}
>   org.wso2.carbon.core.common.AuthenticationException: Authentication Failed : Invalid remote address passed - 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1
>     at org.wso2.carbon.core.services.authentication.AuthenticationUtil.validateRemoteAddress(AuthenticationUtil.java:178)
>     at org.wso2.carbon.core.services.authentication.AuthenticationUtil.getRemoteAddress(AuthenticationUtil.java:156)
>       at org.wso2.carbon.core.services.authentication.AbstractAuthenticator.getRemoteAddress(AbstractAuthenticator.java:304)
>       at org.wso2.carbon.core.services.authentication.AbstractAuthenticator.authenticate(AbstractAuthenticator.java:136)
>       at org.wso2.carbon.server.admin.module.handler.AuthenticationHandler.isAuthenticated(AuthenticationHandler.java:171)
>   {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.util.CarbonAuthenticationUtil}

Is there some way to turn off the remote address validation?